# Angular 10 : Observable not working as expected

Tags: html, angular, typescript

when i call `addPost()` first time observable call working as i expected with 5 sec delay but second time without delay data updating in html. 
same observable with `deletePost()` is working Fine

**data.service.ts**

```js
addPost(post: PostData):Observable<PostData[]>{
    
    this.posts.push( post);
    return this.createObservable(this.posts);
  }

  createObservable(posts: PostData[]): Observable<PostData[]>  {
    return Observable.create(
      (observer) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(posts);
        }, 5000);
      }
    )
  }

deletePost(i:number):Observable<PostData[]>{
  this.posts.splice(i,1)
  return this.createObservable(this.posts);

  }
```

**post-form.component.html**

```html
<ul *ngFor ="let post of posts$|async | filter:searchPost  ;let i = index">
<li>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addPost()" ><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Post</button>
 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" id="delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deletePost(i)" *ngIf="username=='admin'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> 
</li>
</ul>
```

Full Code is  [Here](https://github.com/chethan1996/Online-Voting-System/tree/stack-over-flow)

Comment: What's the point of the observable, if nobody's observing? In your `PostFormComponent` you have the `posts$` observable, but it's write-only. You don't subscribe to it in the typescript, nor put it in the template and consume with the `async` pipe.

Comment: i'm just mocking API Service here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RxJS only.
Something like this should work:

```
createObservable(posts: PostData[]): Observable<PostData[]>  {
   return timer(5000).pipe(mapTo(posts)); 
}
```

I dont see why you need a timer but I trust you with that.

Comment: above code also working same as my code first call works fine after that i'm receiving immediate response without delay

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use Subject for create "delay" on transmissions.

**data.service.ts**

```
posts: PostData[] = []
subject$: Subject<PostData[]> = new Subject<PostData[]>();
obsSubject$: Observable<PostData[]>= this.subject$.asObservable().pipe(switchMap(posts) => from(posts).pipe(timer(100)));

addPost(post: PostData):Observable<PostData[]>{
  this.posts.push(post);
  this.nextPostSubject(this.posts);
}

nextPostSubject(posts: PostData[]): void {
  this.subject.next(posts);
}

deletePost(i:number):void { 
   this.posts.splice(i,1) 
  this.nextPostSubject(this.post);
}
```

**post-form.component.html**

```
     <ul *ngFor ="let post of obsSubject$ |async | filter:searchPost  ;let i = index">
    <li>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addPost()" ><i class="fa fa- 
   send"></i> Post</button>
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" id="delete" data- 
   toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deletePost(i)" *ngIf="username=='admin'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> 
    </li>
    </ul>
```